# What is the difference between http_basic_authenticate_with AND authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic?

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What is the difference between

```
http_basic_authenticate_with()
```

and

```
authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic()
```

methods?

Thanks for your full explanation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From what I can understand from the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic), `http_basic_authenticate_with` acts as a before filter which accepts a name and password such as

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "dhh", :password => "secret", :except => :index
```

Whereas authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic accepts a block allowing for you to insert some code to determine whether they should be authenticated ([documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods/authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic)). E.g.

```
before_filter :authenticate

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Administration') do |username, password|
    ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(username, "admin") &&
    ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(password, "password")
  end
end
```

Comment: And **to test at the controller level**, use `@request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'Basic ' + Base64::encode64('username:password')` then `get :your_action`. Ref: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods/authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic#197-Testing-protected-controllers

Comment: `http_basic_authenticate_with` actually calls `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic` internally. See the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb#L69).